# Entity Framework calling stored procedure expects parameter which was not supplied

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, entity-framework, stored-procedures

I am calling my SP via Entity Framework like this :

```
NextSuperGroup supergroup = entities.Database.SqlQuery<NextSuperGroup>(
      "super_group @user, @orderbyUnique",
      new SqlParameter("@user", userName),
      new SqlParameter("@orderbyUnique", true)).First();
```

And getting the error

> Procedure or function 'super_group' expects parameter '@orderbyUnique', which was not supplied.

As you can see above I am supplying it.

Here's the stored procedure:

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[super_group]
     @user nvarchar(30)
    ,@stepLockDelay varchar(10) = '00:00:00'
    ,@orderbyUnique bit
AS
```

Any ideas why I am getting this error ?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

It probably should complain about the @user parameter as well if this is the case, but anyway - try to supply the parameter without the @ prefix:

```
NextSuperGroup supergroup = entities.Database.SqlQuery<NextSuperGroup>(
    "super_group @user, @orderbyUnique",
    new SqlParameter("user", userName),
    new SqlParameter("orderbyUnique", true)
).First();
```

Answer (score 14):

The issue is the SQL that EF is producing for NULL values must not be compatible with our actual Sql Server. I'm using EntityFramework 6, but I don't think the implementation has changed since 4.3.

When I turned on tracing I get the following output after executing similar code to yours above:

```
exec sp_executesql N'super_group',N'@userName nvarchar(4000)',@userName=default
```

The issue lies in the "default" value passed instead of "NULL" and the error we see comes from SQL server. If you want a quick fix and don't need named parameters you can just use this:

```
NextSuperGroup supergroup = entities.Database.SqlQuery<NextSuperGroup>(
   "super_group",
    userName).First();
```

Which produces something like this and works nicely:

```
exec sp_executesql N'super_group',N'@p0 nvarchar(4000)',@p0=NULL
```

For named parameters, you need to use the sql parameter and set the value or SqlValue property explicitly to DBNull.Value (Crazy I know). Something like this:

```
var parameter = new SqlParameter("userName", SqlDbType.VarChar);
parameter.SqlValue = username.SqlNullIfEmpty(); // Implemented with an extension method
```

Hope that helps.

Comment: Perfect answer! You made my day with that!

Comment: Had this even when specifying the SQL Param, but one of the values passing in with the parameters was null.  Set the default value, and everything was good.

Answer (score 3):

Parameter not passed issue when multiple parameter passed

I was missing 'SPACE' after the first parameter's 'COMMA'

```
var parameter = new List<object>();
var param = new SqlParameter("@CategoryID", CategoryID);
parameter.Add(param);
param = new SqlParameter("@SubCategoryID", SubCategoryID);
parameter.Add(param);

List<tbl_Product> QueryResult = db.Database.SqlQuery<tbl_Product>("EXEC SP_GetProducts @CategoryID, @SubCategoryID ", parameter.ToArray()).ToList();
```

Answer (score 2):

I my case I fixed the issue by explicitly adding the type to parameter I was passing in which was defined in the stored procedure as a bit

```
        var paramExcludeExported = new SqlParameter
        {
            ParameterName = "ExcludeExported",
            SqlDbType = SqlDbType.Bit,
            Value = 0
        };
```

Answer (score 0):

In our case, it was a matter of ensuring that the first letter of parameter was not a number, but a letter.

Changed 6cb to p6cb and the problem went away.

Answer (score -1):

In my case issue was nullable, I was sending `int?` nullable to store procedure parameter int. where nullable must be converted to `nvarchar(4000)`.